# want to edit resource of confirmation mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise 3.3.0 and I applied confirmable function for user.

It work fine, when new user sign up it send confirmation email to his email id. 
Its send mail -

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></p>
```

when I check it on terminal, it send link -

```
<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=D1Eyxrst5rK3q5fJYXSg">Confirm my account</a></p>
```

But url of my application is '**demo.localhost.com:3000**'

and confimable send link localhost:3000, I want to edit this resource link to demo.localhost.com:3000.

I think for that I should edit **@resource** but where is it define and how I edit it? Or there is any better way to pass my url in confirmation mail?

Comment: Are you sure your URL of the app is `demo.localhost.com:3000`?

Comment: yes. my app running on http://demo.localhost.com:3000/

Comment: Is your app running on `localhost`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it through by setting the ***default url options*** for ***Action Mailer*** in  `config/environments/development.rb`(If your app is in development) as below

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'demo.localhost', port: 3000 }
```

Now the generated url will look like

```
<p><a href="http://demo.localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=D1Eyxrst5rK3q5fJYXSg">Confirm my account</a></p>
```